# Azure Worker role not starting after upgrade to Visual studio 2015 and Azure Sdk 2.8.2

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have Web Application that used to work fine on Visual Studio 2012 and Azure Sdk 2.5 and would like to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 and Azure Sdk 2.8.2.

It builds without any problems and runs in emulator with no problems.

When I deploy to Windows Azure the role i get this message -

"Recycling (Waiting for role to start... Sites were deployed. [2016-02-11...])"

I found the below error messages in the windows event viewer in remote login...

**Error Message 1:**

```
 System 

 Provider 

 [ Name]  Application Error 

  EventID 1000 

 [ Qualifiers]  0 

  Level 2 

  Task 100 

 Keywords 0x80000000000000 

 TimeCreated 

 [ SystemTime]  2016-02-11T05:43:24.000000000Z 

 EventRecordID 8425 

 Channel Application 

 Computer RD00155DF88E6C 

 Security 


 EventData 

 WaWorkerHost.exe 
 2.7.1198.742 
 5637c827 
 KERNELBASE.dll 
 6.2.9200.17366 
 554d4531 
 e0434352 
 000000000004aea8 
 884 
 01d1648f1e7cfdf5 
 E:\base\x64\WaWorkerHost.exe 
 D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 
 5d28a4a7-d082-11e5-9403-00155df88e6c
```

**Error Message 2:**

```
System 

 Provider 

 [ Name]  .NET Runtime 

 EventID 1026 

 [ Qualifiers]  0 

 Level 2 

 Task 0 

 Keywords 0x80000000000000 

 TimeCreated 

 [ SystemTime]  2016-02-11T05:43:24.000000000Z 

 EventRecordID 8424 

 Channel Application 

 Computer RD00155DF88E6C 

 Security 


 EventData 

 Application: WaWorkerHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:      The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException Stack: at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0() at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project refers to upgraded version of SDK assemblies like Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime. Apparently, upgrading the solution to latest SDK doesn't update assembly reference. You may also have to update your config file for correct assembly version.